# Pack in an octet string

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filling an octet string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231464/filling-an-octet-string)

I have 65 parameters of different bit length which I need to fill in an octet string. Parametrs would be filled continuously in octet string. For example, suppose the first parameter is 1 bit long so it would be filled at 0th bit position of 1st octet of the octet string. Now the second parameter is suppose 9 bit long. So the first 7 bits of this parametr would be filled in the same octet and the next 2 bits should go to 0th and 1st bit position of next octet. Similarly other parameters would get filled in the octet string. I tried to write a function where in I passed the pointer to the current octet, the bit position and the source pointer from where data would get copied. But I find difficulty in logic implemetation. I have tried numerous logics(bit operation, bit shifting, rotation etc.) but could not get the correct one. I would greatly appreciate if someone can give me a logic/function in "C" to do so. You can use different function prototype also.

Comment: provide the work you did even if it's not completed

Comment: the data that you want to put into the octet string, should be a pointer to a  32 bits of memory. isn't ? and you should provide also the length of your bits with the data pointer isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "bitstream", and is fairly common in e.g. low-level networking protocols.

If there's a reasonable upper bound on your parameters, e.g. 32 bits, you should think in terms of implementing something like:

```
void bitstream_append(uint32_t value, uint8_t bits);
```

which would append the `bits` rightmost bits of `value` to the stream. It might help to think how you would implement that if you already had `bitstream_append_bit(bool bit);`.

Comment: Yes the upper bound is 32 bit. I have one parameter of size 32 bit two of 16 bits and rest are of 8 bit. So there is a upper bound of 32 bit. Anyways thanks for the help. But I actuaaly look for the logic.

Comment: @user1958240 Since you didn't provide any code showing what you've tried, I was trying to guide you onto the right (or at least a workable) path. Perhaps you should try to implement the functions I outlined, and post the results in the question.

Comment: Sure.I am working on that.